# Notify component about error in service - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In pre-version 8 `Angular` one could `subscribe()` to both `success` and `error` Observables from the `component` object therefore if service operation completed successfully, `component` would perform one action and on error `component` could perform a different one. However, in Angular 8, that pattern was depreciated and instead, one needs to subscribe to success but errors are handled by the `service` object, in custom generic error handler methods. Benefit of that approach is clear and understandable. Angular documentation provides good example in article here: https://angular.io/guide/http , hence my question: what is the recommended pattern to notify `component` about error in `service` execution in Angular 8 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had to ask the question to come up with answer, lol

Pre Angular 8 method call was: `service.method().subscribe((result)=>{...}, (error)=>{...})`

Angular 8 and higher: `service.method().subscribe({next: (result)=>{..}, error: (error)=>{...}})`

As simple as that, Art